# How to avoid downcasing acronyms in ruby / rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a field that contains titles like "IT Professional" or "DB Administrator". 
I want to display this in the middle of a sentence and so need to down-case. Unfortunately, this also downcases the acronyms and I end up with "Thanks for joining a community of it professionals".

A good start would be the solution mentioned by Grantovich below, i.e. specifying my acronyms  in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym "IT"
  inflect.acronym "DB"
end
```

The problem with going this route is that firstly, I don't want to store them in lower case as suggested as part of the solution because they are titles and should be stored with capitals.  Secondly, they are already defined in uppercase and it would be a bad idea to suddenly make them lower case.

Solution Found: Since I want the title to appear in the middle of a sentence, hence the need for lower case, I solved it by downcasing the title, constructing the sentence and then calling #humanize on that. Humanize will capitalize the first letter of the sentence and any defined acronyms.

Comment: It may be easier to store the lower case form of the phrases and convert to title case when needed. That transformation has less exceptions.

Comment: maybe this? `string.downcase.gsub('it professional', 'IT professional')` not clean at all, but you could have a helper method that would scan the string and replace the down-cased strings to their proper form, make it flexible, use a Regexp, etc.

Comment: Would you output the before string and the expected output? There is confusion of 'IT Professional' vs 'IT professional'

Comment: -1. Question is not clear. Define acronyms (without relying on encyclopediaeic knowledge). Or, do you want to have an Artificial Intelligence or a huge database as part of the code? How do you expect the string `"I thank John for joining our community of IT Professionals"` to be downcased?

Comment: I noticed you have edited in the solution you chose. If you have time, it is worth posting this in the answer box - i.e. answering your own question. Include code if you can. You can then mark it as accepted, which is useful for people browsing your question in future.

Comment: Would be happy to but the question was "put on hold" and locked.

Comment: Your proposed solution has a major flaw: it will capitalize the word "it" if it appears in your sentence. `#humanize` may have other undesirable side effects when used on sentences -- it's mostly intended for prettying up column and association names.

Answer (score 6):

If possible, I would store the strings as "IT professional", "DB administrator", etc. with all letters except for the acronyms already downcased. Then you can [add your acronyms to the inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) and use `#titleize` to convert to title case when needed. In terms of edge cases and code maintenance burden, this is a better solution than writing your own code to do "selective downcasing".

Comment: Yes, this is clearly easier than going down the rabbit hole of detecting intended acronyms in already title-cased text, even when it involves manually adjusting 100s of rows of existing data, and re-factoring current displays to use `#titleize`.

Comment: Something like Alex Peachey's solution might still be required if you don't have full control over the input data. Maybe it comes from an external service, or new values are added by users (making it infeasible to maintain the acronym list). Thus the key phrase here is "If possible". =)

Answer (score 5):

If we assume that by acronym, you mean any word in your string that is made of 2 or more capitals in a row, then you could do something like this:

```
def smart_case(field)
  field.to_s.split(' ').map { |word|
    /[A-Z][A-Z]+/.match(word) ? word : word.downcase
  }.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: `split` is the same as `split(' ')`.

Comment: This is not your fault (it is the OP's fault), but I don't think it is that simple. Your code will downcase names like `"John"`, or the personal pronoun `"I"`.

Comment: `/[A-Z][A-Z]+/` won't match `"I"`, but your other point is correct. Given the strings in question seem to be job titles it's unlikely that either `"I"` or a person's name would show up, but the problem could manifest for e.g. `"Java Developers"`, where Java should remain capitalized.

Comment: @Grantovich `/[A-Z][A-Z]+/` won't match `"I"`, and that is why it will be downcased. I don't understand why you particularly mention my "other point is correct".

Comment: You're right, I had my logic mixed up somehow.

Comment: Given the set up from the OP, "field that contains titles", I have no reason to believe names or "I" would show up. That being said, the point about "Java Developers" may hold true.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ugly way to do it but:

```
def format_me(str)
  str.downcase!
  @acronymn_words = ["IT Professional", "DB Administrator"]
  @acronymn_words.each do |a|
    if str.include? a.downcase
      str.gsub!(a.downcase,a)
    end
  end
  capitalize_next = true
  str = str.split.map  do |word|
    if capitalize_next then word.capitalize! end 
    capitalize_next = word.end_with?(".","!","?")
    word
    end.join(" ")
end
```

This would be difficult to maintain unless you know the exact strings you are looking for but it will put out a correctly formatted sentence with the items you requested.

Comment: This is not flexible, but the only way to go.

Comment: @sawa I agree although it will still contain the same issues you have list above such as proper names and words like I unless you include all of them in the initial array too which would be extremely cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this like that :

```
do_not_downcase = ["IT", "DB"] # Complete the list with your favourites words
res = ""
str.split(" ").each do |word|
    if !do_not_downcase.include? word then
        res += word.downcase + " "
    else
        res += word + " "
    end
end

puts res

>welcome IT professionals
```

Comment: I though of this too but IT could also just be the word it in which case it should be downcased and I think he wants Professional and Administrator also left in Proper case.